# How to properly partition code in a C# functional library?

Tags: c#, functional-programming

As a premise one of a key difference of FP design about reusable libraries (for what I'm learning), is that these are more data-centric that corresponding OO (in general).

This seems confirmed also from emerging techniques like **TFD** (Type-First-Development), well explained by Tomas Petricek in [this](http://tomasp.net/blog/type-first-development.aspx) blog post.

Nowadays language are multi-paradigm and the same Petricek in its book explains various functional techniques usable from C#.

What I'm interested here and, hence the question, **is how to properly partition code**.

So I've defined library data structures, using the equivalent of discriminated unions (as shown in Petricek book), and I project to use them with immutable lists and/or tuples *according to the domain logic of mine requirements*.

Where do I place operations (methods ... functions) that acts on data structures?

If I want define an high-order function that use a function value embodied in a standard delegates `Func<T1...TResult>`, where do I place it?

Common sense says me to group these methods in static classes, but I'd like a confirmation from people that already wrote functional libs in C#.

Assuming that this is correct and I've an high-order function like this:

```
static class AnimalTopology {
  IEnumerable<Animal> ListVertebrated(Func<Skeleton, bool> selector) {
    // remainder omitted
  }
}
```

If *choosing vertebrated animal* has N particular cases that I want to expose in the library, what's the more correct way to expose them.

```
static class VertebratedSelectorsA {
  // this is compatible with "Func<Skeleton, bool> selector"
  static bool Algorithm1(Skeleton s) {
    //...
  } 
}
```

or

```
static class VertebratedSelectorsB {
  // this method creates the function for later application
  static Func<Skeleton, bool> CreateAlgorithm1Selector(Skeleton s) {
     // ...
  } 
}
```

Any indication will be very appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I want to quote two phrases from T. Petricek, [Real World Functional Programming](http://goo.gl/M2M3w) foreword by Mads Torgersen:

> [...] You can use functional programming techniques in C# to great benefit,
>   though it is easier and more natural to do so in F#.
>   [...]
>   Functional programming is a state of mind. [...]

**EDIT-2:**

- I feel there's a necessity to further clarify the question. The **functional** mentioned in the title strictly relates to [Functional Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming); I'm not asking the more *functional* way of grouping methods, in the sense of more logic way or the the way that make more sense in general.
- This implies that the implementation will try to follow as more as possible founding concepts of FP summarized by [NOOO](http://notonlyoo.org/) manifesto and quoted here for convenience and clarity:

> 1. Functions and Types over classes
> 2. Purity over mutability
> 3. Composition over inheritance
> 4. Higher-order functions over method dispatch
> 5. Options over nulls

The question is around **how to layout a C# library wrote following FP concepts**, so (for example) it's absolutely not an option putting methods inside data structure; because this is a founding Object-Oriented paradigm.

**EDIT-3:**

Also if the question got response (and various comments), I don't want give the wrong impression that there has been said that one programming paradigm is superior than another.
As before I'll mention an authority on FP, Don Syme, in its book Expert F# 3.0 (ch.20 - Designing F# Libraries - pg.565):

> [...] It's a common misconception that the functional and OO programming methodologies compete; in fact, they're largely orthogonal. [...]

Comment: Static I think would be good for fluent configurators, but not so great for data handlers... all sorts of opportunity for cross-mojination.

Comment: Jeremy Holovacs, with the latest term you mean the adjustment of FP techniques in multi-paradigm languages?

Comment: I mean static classes really defeat the purpose of object-oriented programming.  Global scopes are vulnerable to unexpected modifications and are very difficult to test.

Comment: In fact the question is about designing functional library from multi-paradigm lang like C#. I'm talking of static types that just hold static methods. Construct like class are used to mimic functional artifacts in this case not to define an OO design.

Comment: but C# really isn't that "multi-paradigm".  It is very clearly an object-oriented language that supports some procedural stuff, but that is not its focus.  You can shoehorn a function library into the language, but you're better off using a procedural language.  Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs, not sure to agree. FP concepts can be applied in C# (see Petricek book). Linq is functional and is built-in in the compiler; Reactive Extensions are functional. For quote two famous one...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language), while C# is a multi-paradigm language, "C# is intended to be a simple, modern, general-purpose, object-oriented programming language"... I think you are trying to fit a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27156/discussion-between-jay-and-jeremy-holovacs)

Comment: Outside chat, I want to leave it a comment in response to what says wikipedia about C#. First it states that is multi-paradigm than it highlight that it's object-oriented: as it were the only preponderant feature. I want to point out this [great post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/01/07/RoleHints/) by Mark Seemann. Let me quote him: "[...] many so-called object-oriented languages aren't really object-oriented, but rather class-oriented. This is as true for C# as for Java. The code artifacts are classes (or interfaces, etc.); not objects.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Note:** If you want a shorter, more-to-the-point answer, see my other answer. I am aware that this one here *might* seem to ramble & go on forever & talk past your issue, but perhaps it will give you a few ideas.

It is difficult to answer your question without knowing the exact relationship between `Animal` and `Skeleton`. I will make a recommendation about this relationship in the second half of my answer, but before I do that, I will simply go along with what I see in your post.

First I will try to infer a few things from your code:

```
static class AnimalTopology
{
    // Note: I made this function `static`... or did you omit the keyword on purpose?
    static IEnumerable<Animal> ListVertebrated(Func<Skeleton, bool> selector)
    {
        …
    }
}
```

1. If you have designed that function according to functional principles, it should have no side-effects. That is, its output relies only on its arguments. (And in a semi-object-oriented setting, perhaps on other static members of `AnimalTopology`; but since you didn't show any, let us ignore that possibility.)
2. If the function is indeed side-effect-free (and does not access static members of `AnimalTopology`), then the function's type signature suggests that it is possible to derive an `Animal` from a `Skeleton`, because it accepts something that acts on `Skeleton`s and returns `Animal`s.
3. If this is also true, then let me assume the following for the sake of being able to give an answer:

   ```
   class Skeleton
   {
       …
       public Animal Animal { get { … } } // Skeletons have animals!? We'll get to that.
   }
   ```

Now it is obvious that your function is impossible to implement, since it could derive `Animal`s from `Skeleton`s, but it doesn't receive any `Skeleton` at all; it only receives a predicate function that acts on a `Skeleton`. (You could fix this by adding a second parameter of type `Func<IEnumerable<Skeleton>> getSkeletons`, but...)

In my opinion, something like the following would make more sense:

```
static IEnumerable<Animal> GetVertebrates(this IEnumerable<Skeleton> skeletons,
                                          Func<Skeleton, bool> isVertebrate)
{
    return skeletons
           .Where(isVertebrate)
           .Select(s => s.Animal);
}
```

---

Now, one might wonder why you are guessing animals from their skeletons; and isn't the `bool` property "is vertebrate" an inherent property of an animal (or skeleton)? Are there really several ways to decide on this?

I would suggest the following:

```
class Animal
{
     Skeleton Skeleton { get; } // not only vertebrates have skeletons! 
}

class Vertebrate : Animal { … } // vertebrates are a kind of animal 

static class AnimalsExtensions
{
    static IEnumerable<Vertebrate> ThatAreVertebrates(this IEnumerable<Animal> animals)
    {
        return animals.OfType<Vertebrate>();
    }
}
```

Please note the use of extension methods above. Here's an example how to use it:

```
List<Animal> animals = …;
IEnumerable<Vertebrate> vertebrates = animals.ThatAreVertebrates();
```

---

Now suppose your extension method did more complex work. In that case, it might be a good idea to put it inside its own designated "algorithm type":

```
interface IVertebrateSelectionAlgorithm
{
    IEnumerable<Vertebrate> GetVertebrates(IEnumerable<Animal> animals);
}
```

This has the advantage that it can be set up / parameterized e.g. via a class constructor; and you could split up the algorithm into several methods that all reside in the same class (but are all `private` except for `GetVertebrates`.)

Of course you can do the same kind of parameterization with functional closures, but in my experience that quickly gets messy in a C# setting. Here, classes are a good means to group a set of functions together as one logical entity.

Comment: +1 for some good points through the analysis (that will be investigated). I've to disagree that you need to need know more about sample code artifacts in the question. The question is: "I have `X`, `Y` and `Z` data structures. How are general guidelines to organize operations on these, again in a C# library built with FP concepts?".

Comment: @Jay: Perhaps you should define what you mean by _"organize operations"_. I understand it approximately as a two-part question: **1.** "Where to I put my functions?" See my other answer about this. Note in particular that C# has no global functions. **2.** "How do my functions relate `X`, `Y`, and `Z` / put them in some kind of a relationship, or association?" You will *always* have to answer that question when you write a library. It doesn't matter that you want to use C#, or a functional programming paradigm.

Comment: This answers, and other +1 for the edit (in the comment of the other question). This edit centers the point in a more clear way, give good suggestions and explain taken choices.

Answer (score 2):

> *Where do I place operations (methods ... functions) that acts on data structures?*

I see four common approaches (in no particular order):

- Put the functions inside the data structures. (This is the **object-oriented "method"** approach. It is suitable when a function acts only on an instance of that type. It is perhaps less appropriate e.g. when a function "draws together" several objects of different types, and spits out an object of yet another type. In this case, I would...)
- Put the functions inside their own designated **"algorithm classes"**. (This seems reasonable when the functions do much or complex work, or need to be parameterized/configured, or where you might want to split the algorithm into several functions that you can then logically "group" together by putting them in a class type.)
- Turn the functions into **lambdas** (a.k.a. anonymous delegates, closures, etc.). (This works well if they're small and you only need them in one specific place; the code won't be easily reusable in a different place.)
- Put the functions in a static class and make them **extension methods**. (That's how LINQ to Objects works. It is a hybrid functional & object-oriented approach. It takes some extra care to get the discoverability / namespacing issue right. Many people will think this approach breaks "encapsulation" when taken too far. For a counter-argument, read the excellent C++ article ["How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation"](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197); substitute "extension method" for "non-member friend function".)

> **Note:** I could go into each of these in more detail if people want, but before I do that, I'll wait and see what kind of feedback this answer receives.

Comment: +1 also for this. I've also to say **this synthetic question catch the point better than the longest one**. But I've to say that point 1 (about OO approach) is not clearly presented. Since the question is about FP, it should proposed here as a sort of anti-pattern.

Comment: @Jay: Despite all its (newer) functional features, C# is still much more an object-oriented language than anything else. As long as it doesn't permit global functions, you by necessity have to put your functions someplace else; namely inside a type. The only question remaining is, *which type* should contain a particular function? OO dictates that methods should be as close to the data that they operate on. Only when you cannot clearly point your finger at one type would you (e.g.) put a method in in its own "service" class or make it an extension method in a static class.

Comment: @jay: Frankly, if you want to take functional programming *all the way*, and you cannot accept *at least some* object-orientation, then C# is quite simply not the right language for you. It doesn't do C# justice to call one of its most fundamental features (instance methods) an anti-pattern. Keep your mind open, perhaps there are cases when they are a good thing!